# How is it that the voltage wave along a circuit is a tenth of the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, electrons

I have heard that the voltage  wave (pushing the electrons) along a circuit is a tenth of the speed of light. Can someone please explain with an illustration how it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Start by considering a long pipe with water flowing through it. We'll assume the rate of flow is slow, so the *current* of water is small. This means water entering the pipe at one end will take a long time to flow all the way along the pipe to the other end.

However suppose we generate a pressure wave at one end of the pipe. A pressure wave in water is just a sound wave, and the sound wave will travel along the pipe at the speed of sound in water or about 1,500 m/sec. This is much much faster than the speed the water is flowing along the pipe.

Now the point of this is that electrons flowing in a wire behave similary to water flowing in a pipe. Electrons flow in one end of the wire (e.g. from a battery), flow along the wire and eventually out of the other end. The average speed of the electrons is called the [drift velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity), and in normal circumstances it's pretty slow. Typical drift velocities are in the 1 mm/sec range, which is a lot less than the speed of light!

But for electrons in a wire an electrical signal is equivalent to a sound wave flowing in our pipe full of water. Electrical signals are effectively compression waves travelling through the electrons in the wire. This "speed of sound" for electrons in the wire is much faster than the drift velocity, and in fact it is around 0.1$c$ just as your question says.